# How to correctly use Jade.render?

Tags: pug

Recently I found that Jade is a very cool template.

But the API seems a bit confusing to me.

On its official page (http://jade-lang.com/api/) it defines the `options` object as follows:

```
{
  filename:string
  pretty:boolean
  self:boolean
  debug:boolean
  compileDebug:boolean
  compiler:class
  globals:array
}
```

But when I searched some other docs, I found that I can pass in a JSON object as injecting variables to my template, which would replace things like `#{something_in_json.value}`

And the JSON is like:

`"something_in_json":"this is a value"}`

My question is, what should I do if I want to use both features? I want to pass in JSON variables and also use the parameters (for example, I want to use `pretty:true`).

Comment: What is your actual ``jade.render`` code?

Comment: My code is `var html = jade.render(jade_source, options);` where, `jade_source` is a jade string, using `fs.readFileSync` to get from a template; `options` is a parsed JSON object also using `fs.readFileSync` to get from a JSON file but parsed after reading the file. I put my content in it. FYI, I use this for supporting multiply languages, so I have a lot of JSON objects.

Comment: I think the only solution is to merge your json data with jade options and pass it as 2nd argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're 2 ways to do this

1. Merge your JSON data with Jade's options

   ```
   // assuming jQuery is available
   $.extend(data, jade_options, json_data);
   jade.render(jade_source, data);
   ```
2. Use Jade's compile function instead, a bit uglier

   ```
   var fn = jade.compile(jade_source, jade_options);
   fn(data); // returns compiled jade template e.g. <html>...
   ```

Comment: Thanks. So the `data` and `options` can be actually in one JSON. Does that mean I can't use `#{pretty}` because it's a default keyword?

Comment: Yes, I also think it's not intuitive to mix both options and data in one object, but with 2nd approach `data` and `options` are not mixed in one object